# How to change maximum number of users within a WSO2 IS tenat

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

Using the multi-tenancy model of WSO2 Identity Server, I found out that there is a limit of 100 users per tenant (as the 101th failed to be created). Where is this limitation defined?

FYI, for convenient I'm using the "Demo" plan, as I am not required to hold multiple tenants models.

Comment: AFAIK there is no limitation as such. What is the IS version and the error that you get?

Comment: OK, thank you. Indeed there is no limitation on the number of users created, just that 'listUsers("*", -1)' is hard coded limited to 100 users. I had to switch to 'getUserList' to get the full list and find the real number of users existing.